# Connection between an IA input and a preamp's DC/DC converter

Tags: operational-amplifier

There is this circuit shown in [Burr-Brown: Instrumentation Amplifier Handbook: High-Side Current Sensing (page 74)](https://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/Burr%20Brown/_contents/Burr-Brown%20The%20Instrumentation%20Amplifier%20Handbook.pdf) that has an IA (INA117) input tied to the COM (0V?) of a DC/DC converter (DCP011515DP). The DC/DC converter provides a stable supply to the pre-amp OPA277. I don't see how that converter has anything to do with INA117.

I understand the general idea of the OPA277 that is to gain up the 50mV shunt by 200V/V and to have a 10V maximum differential voltage going into INA117. But why is there this connection between INA117 and the DC/DC Converter's COM (indicated in yellow)?

[image]

- The 150V polarity is drawn incorrectly and should be reversed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INA117 is a High Common-Mode Voltage Difference Amplifier, so, this circuit would work well if the *CMMR* was infinite and the *input voltage offset* was zero:

[image]

It would also work with decent precision **with** the CMMR and input voltage offset in the order of mV, **if** instead of a 50 mV shunt, a 10 V shunt was possible (but this would result in significant reduction of the load current).

So, to amplify the shunt voltage, a precision op. amp. is used, but this component can't handle the high common mode voltage. So, the power rails of this op. amp. must "follow" the high input voltage, by being tied to it using a low resistance path.

[image]

By making the connection you mentioned, all the circuit parts surrounded by the squares will follow the high common mode input voltage. This is possible since the OPA power supply is isolated from its power input, so its potential can be "moved" to the desired voltage level (like the secondary of a transformer).

This image, from the dc-dc converter [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/dcp011515db) shows the internal simplified block diagram of the two isolated circuits:

[image]

The COM pin on the right can be tied to any voltage within the component isolation specs and the \$+V_{OUT}\$ and \$-V_{OUT}\$ will provide voltages relative to this reference.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the DC-DC converter is a type with a floating output and it is just being used to power the differential amp (OPA277). That whole circuit has an artificial common which is near to +150V (so it's positive rail is at about +165V). The INA117 is being used to level shift the amplified voltage from across the sense resistor back down to ground level, to give current sensing for circuit which takes 50A at 150V. Presumably a rather specialised application, but useful if you need it.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of "floating output". So converter pin #2 (COM to ground) is "separated" from the COM at pin #5 which works like a level shifter to whatever voltage is tied to that pin.  If I get what you're saying, at maximum shunt voltage 50mV, pin #5 will be tied to 150V-50mV=149.95V.  What powers OPA277 is 149.95+15V from pin #6 and 149V-15V from pin #7. That way the output voltage level of OPA277 will fall within the supply rail. Did I understand you right?  It's still a strange circuit though -  PSRR will induce a significant input offset from such a big supply shift..

Comment: yes, most likely there is an internal transformer or anyway galvanic isolation between the supply in and the +/0/- output.

Comment: You are correct that the OPA277 circuit is floating with its "0V" reference just below the 150V rail. I don't agree about PSRR though : it's rails are at +/-15V w.r.t. that "0V" and it is quite unaware that it is floating around at +150V. It's job is to turn that +50mV FS sense signal into a negative voltage from 0 to -10V at its output (w.r.t. to its own common reference). The differential input of the INA then removes any common mode and turns that into a 0 to +10V signal properly referenced to the true ground. Both circuits have stable power w.r.t. their own 0V, so PSRR is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The DC/DC converter is generating a dual supply (±15V).  The COM is the 0V reference for the sensing circuit (the Op Amp's "ground").  This whole circuit is "floating" on the 150V power circuit that is being sensed, which is why an isolated power supply is used.

Comment: I only know what is bad with a floating input. Never knew output of a chip can be made "floating" even when the chip itself is referenced to ground (pin #2).  Wouldn't the inputs to the INA117 also has a high CMV though? But it's still powered from a ground referenced +/-15V... strange circuit

Comment: @KMC: Only the input of the converter is referenced to ground. The datasheet says it provides 1kV of isolation. (There's actually a miniature transformer integrated into it!) Yes, the INA117 will have high common-mode voltage.  Look at that datasheet: It is called a "High Common-Mode Voltage Difference Amplifier".  It can handle a common mode voltage of ±200V.